# Error module "QtQuick" version 2.12 is not installed

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

I have installed Qt 4.5.0 community and I am trying to build my project with **Qt5.10.0 MinGW 32 bit**. Having QtQuick 2.12 imported in my qml file in a qtquick project, I face with the following error:

> module "QtQuick" version 2.12 is not installed

It is worth mentioning that this module is among the suggested ones when I try to write the first characters of QtQu...

Would be appreciated if one could help me how to overcome this problem

Comment: Sorry
It even does not predict the QtQuick 2.12. the latest version it suggests is QtQuick2.9

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-index.html#versions):

```
╭------┬---------┬----------------------------┬-------------------╮
|      |         | QtQuick.Controls,          |                   |
|      |         | QtQuick.Controls.Material, |                   |
|  Qt  | QtQuick | QtQuick.Controls.Universal,| Qt.labs.calendar, |
|      |         | QtQuick.Templates          | Qt.labs.platform  |
|      |         |                            |                   |
├------┼---------┼----------------------------┼-------------------┤
| 5.7  |   2.7   |          2.0               |        1.0        |
| 5.8  |   2.8   |          2.1               |        1.0        |     
| 5.9  |   2.9   |          2.2               |        1.0        |
| 5.10 |   2.10  |          2.3               |        1.0        |
| 5.11 |   2.11  |          2.4               |        1.0        |
| 5.12 |   2.12  |          2.12              |        1.0        |
╰------┴---------┴----------------------------┴-------------------╯
```

So in your case you should use `QtQuick 2.10` or earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Is there any method to update the current program? I a method instead of uninstalling the current version and downloading and installing the new version?

Comment: @HoOman If you use the online installer you can update the packages, otherwise you will have to download everything returned